# EM algorithm steps when analytical derivatives are not available

Tags: matlab, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, copula

I am trying to write some MATLAB code in order to estimate regime switching copula models, in the spirit of http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1102632. The nature of the problem renders the use of analytical derivatives next to impossible, therefore the optimization step is being done numerically. Everything looks good except the fact that after every iteration of the EM algorithm, it is not guaranteed that the log likelihood increases. As I understand it, the EM algorithm consists of the following steps (based on http://people.few.eur.nl/kole/rsexample.pdf ):

**Step 0:** Let $\mathbf{\theta^0 } = (\theta_1^0,\theta_2^0,\pi_{11}^0,\pi_{22}^0)$ be the initial parameters vector, where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the regime specific parameters and $\pi_{11}$ and $\pi_{22}$ are the transition probabilities. Calculate $\gamma_{1,1|0} = \dfrac{1-\pi_{11}}{2-\pi_{11}-\pi_{22}}$ and $\gamma_{2,1|0} =1-\gamma_{1,1|0}.$

**Step 1:** Starting from $\bf{\gamma_{1|0}}$ use Hamilton's Filter to calculate the inference and forecasted probabilities by the recursion:

$\bf{\gamma_{t|t}}=\dfrac{\gamma_{t|t-1}\odot n_t}{1'\cdot (\gamma_{t|t-1}\odot n_t)} $(inference probabilities, $n_t$ contains the regimes pdfs)

$\mathbf{\gamma_{t+1|t}=P'\cdot \gamma_{t|t}}$ (forecasted probabilities, P the transition matrix)

**Step2:** Calculate initial Log likelihood $LL_C^0=\sum_{t=1}^T\mathbf{log(1' \cdot (\gamma_{t|t-1}\odot n_t))}.$ Steps 1 and 2 are the E step of the algorithm.

**Step3:** Maximize the log likelihood function to obtain a new set of regime specific parameters $\theta_1^1$ and $\theta_2^1$. Calculate smoothed inference probabilities through Kim's filter and update the transition probabilities to $\pi_{11}^1$ and $\pi_{22}^1.$. When step 3 is complete a new set of $\mathbf{\theta}=(\theta_1^1,\theta_2^1,\pi_{11}^1,\pi_{22}^1) $ and a new value for $\mathbf{\gamma_{1|0}}$ is obtained. Step 3 is the M step of the EM algorithm.

**Step 4:** We repeat steps 1 and 2 to calculate $LL_C^1$. It should hold that $LL_C^1>LL_C^0$. If $LL_C^1 - LL_C^0 > tol,$ repeat steps until convergence.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be highly appreciated.